# Image IO Write not writing

Tags: java, swing, javax.imageio

basically I am trying to save an image I have edited in a JFrame, so I have a menu with the save item and I have an action listener to set up for the save item and everything works fine, the file chooser comes up and I can select where I would like to save it, only thing is when I hit save, its not there. Here is my code, am I missing something?

```
 if(e.getSource().equals(Save)){
        JFileChooser keep = new JFileChooser();
        keep.setSelectedFile(new File ("newImage.jpg"));
        FileNameExtensionFilter  filters = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpeg", "jpg");
        keep.setFileFilter(filters);
        File output = keep.getSelectedFile();

        int count = keep.showSaveDialog(keep);
        BufferedImage out = filteredImage;

        if (count == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){

        }
        else{
            try{
                ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", output);

                //I put this here to see if I was even reaching the method
                System.out.println("writing method");
            }catch(Exception d){
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"am I missing something?" .. `}catch(Exception d){
            }`"* information! 1st change that to `}catch(Exception d){ d.printStackTrace(); }` & run the code again. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: actually I had a JOptionPaneDialog("Your file could not save") but that was printing either, I took it out when I posted it though! Sorry! (I took it out beacuse it orignally said, you just got the d...) EDIT: Ive just added the d.printstacktrace and It didnt print out, so the IMage IO write method is wroking, for some reason its just not showing up where I save it

Comment: Given the number of possible return results from `JFileChooser`, I might suggest you code for the "happy path" first, maybe use something like `if (count == JFileChooser.ACCEPT_OPTION){` instead

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer Ill check that now EDIT: OKay that didnt change anything, I know for sure the write method is getting called because my syso is printing to the console, its just not appearing on my Desktop

Comment: *"..that didnt change anything,"* Something that might change my interest level (and from that help) is that MCVE. Where is it?

Comment: @Elchapo The suggest was just a "general" suggest, most companies I've worked for like "happy" path coding, keeps the devs on the positive side of things ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the tip! haha hours of java debugging has made me a negative nancy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you get a reference to the `selectedFile`...

```
File output = keep.getSelectedFile();
```

The you show the dialog...

```
int count = keep.showSaveDialog(keep);
BufferedImage out = filteredImage;
```

Then you try and save the image...

```
ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", output);
```

...wait, what?!  Assuming that `getSelectedFile` isn't `null`, how do you know where you're actually saving the image?

That process should be reversed slightly...

```
showSaveDialog
if (accepted) {
    saveFile = getSelectedFile
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", saveFile);
}
```

as a basic psudo code example

Comment: Ive just realized its replacing the orignal image now, it doesnt matter where I try to save it or what I save it as it just replaed the original image, which isnt what I want (nor do I understand why/how that happens)

Comment: You use `getSelectedFile` BEFORE you show the `JFileChooser`, you should be using it AFTER, otherwise you are get what was previously selected, if anything

Comment: Thanks! That did it!!